# Laravel Valet replacing public sites with 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I'm learning Laravel, and I successfully installed Valet. Did some basic development. Then moved on to other things totally unrelated. About a week later (today) I visited two sites (in Chrome and Safari Mac):

- postmarkapp.com
- getsatisfaction.com/activeinbox

And I get "Valet - Page Not Found".

I do not get this issue any other website I visit. And I've never seen something selectively take over a site like this. It's obviously related to my local configuration but because I'm new to Valet I have no idea where to start with this.

- What is happening?
- How is this possible?
- How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening?**

Your network configuration is pointing those domains to valet instead of looking them up through external name servers.

**How is this possible**

Laravel Valet uses dnsmasq so you don't have to worry about editing your /etc/hosts file for each dev site you create.  It can step in and provide ip resolution before looking externally for an ip address.

**How do I fix this**

From a terminal run:

```
valet domain test
valet restart
```

My guess is you changed your domain on valet to com and the reason other sites are working is their ip addresses are already cached locally.

Comment: Thank you. This all makes a little more sense. I ran the `valet test` on those two domains and receive "Command X is not defined." Restart executes successfully but the issue persists. Any other ideas? Thank you for your time.

Comment: what exactly did you run?  it should be `valet domain test`  exactly like that, not  adding your own domain

Comment: it wild cards whatever you put at the end of that command... so it will send anything from *.test to valet

Comment: @SpencerHill any luck?

Comment: Thanks, @wheelmaker, I ran "valet postmarkapp.com test" for example originally. But I just ran "valet domain test" literally and it definitely produced a different result in the CLI but these domains are still not accessible. And now it's affecting more domains. Like it's growing or something... Help!

Comment: I had previously reported the solution was to change my DNS from 8.8.8.8 to anything else, such as 1.1.1.1 because it appeared to be getting filtered. But I have since discovered that didn't resolve the issue, although it has to be related somehow because switching it back gets me the same domains with the same result.

I thought this issue had disappeared but it did not.

Although, now it's occurring with other domains. Today it's https://www.techspot.com/article/1357-customize-chrome-new-tab-page/

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, you will need the public folder.

To get this, copy the `public_html` and duplicate it.

Proceed to rename it to `public`

If it's a new project, create the .env file and run `php artisan key:generate`

Then `valet restart` and you'll be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `public/index.php` exists and has not been deleted by mistake.